# how to change color scheme from purple to any other color(green) in honey comb?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to change the color scheme of my app from purple to green via code as my app's basic color is green. Basically i want to change the color of the shade that comes on scrolling and the color shade behind the dialog box, by default its purple yet i wannt change to green when my user is in my app.

Regards
MGD